# Python regex to detect string in multiline

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to detect a string, sometime it appears as one line and sometimes it appears as multiline.

case 1:

```
==================== 1 error in 500.14 seconds =============
```

case 2:

```
 ================= 3 tests deselected by "-m 'not regression'" ==================
 21 failed, 553 passed, 35 skipped, 3 deselected, 4 error, 51 rerun in 6532.96 seconds
```

I have tried the following thing but it's not working

```
==+.*(?i)(?m)(error|failed).*(==+|seconds)
```

Comment: What content do you need to match on the second string?

Comment: Failed tests. **xx failed** or **xx error**

Comment: Is there any reason why `\d+ failed|\d+ error` wouldn't be enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex:

```
==+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s(error|failed).*(==+|seconds)
```

- `[\s\S]` instead of `.` allows line delimiters as well
- `(\d+)` is the first matching group so `matches[0]` will always contains the number such as 1 or 21
- `(error|failed)` is the second matching group so `matches[1]` will contain either 'error' or 'failed'

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WtO84B/1)

Testing in Python:

```
import re

pattern = "==+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s(error|failed).*(==+|seconds)"
case1 = "==================== 1 error in 500.14 seconds ============="
p = re.compile(pattern)
matches = p.match(case1).groups()
matches[0] + " " + matches[1]   # Output: '1 error'

case2 = """================= 3 tests deselected by -m 'not regression' ==================
 21 failed, 553 passed, 35 skipped, 3 deselected, 4 error, 51 rerun in 6532.96 seconds"""
matches = p.match(case2).groups()
matches[0] + " " + matches[1]   # Output: '21 failed'
```

Hope this helps!